# App installation failed, Bundle identifier must be unique ~ Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, identifier

> App installation failed
>
> This application or a bundle it contains has the same bunndle
> identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains.
> Bundle identifier must be unique.

please help, thanks!

Comment: you are trying to install an app that has same bundle identifier as another app on your device... bundle identifier is usually as `something.something.something`...

Comment: no bro it is not correct

Comment: I'm getting this same problem and my app does not contain any app extensions.

Have you found an answer?

Comment: This solved the issue for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344160/failed-to-set-plugin-placeholders-message/48094623#48094623